# Python - Find top largest numbers in array

Tags: python, math, sorting

Okay - I have a dilemma. So far my script converts page titles into categories. This is based on keywords, and when there is a match a certain score is added, I.e some words hold the value of 10, some only 1. This gets accumulated into a total score for each category.

```
[{15: [32, 'massages']}, {45: [12, 'hair-salon']}, {23,:[3, 'automotive service']}]
```

Index being the category id, first value the score second value the category.

In some instances this spans to over 10 category matches.

How can I filter this to only the top 60-75%

I.e clearly massages and hair salon are the most as they are well above automotive service. But how can this intelligence we use be programmed?

I was thinking stddev could help?

**Edit**

I am trying to filter out low scoring items e.g.

```
data = [{15: [32, 'massages']}, {45: [1, 'hair-salon']}, {23:[1, 'automotive service']}]]
```

Massages is the only high scoring item in this instance

```
data = [{15: [4, 'massages']}, {45: [2, 'hair-salon']}, {23:[1, 'automotive service']}]]
```

Stil massages

```
data = [{15: [10, 'massages']}, {45: [50, 'hair-salon']}, {23:[5, 'automotive service']}]]
```

Now hair-salon (as it is well above others)

So I need not take the first (N) objects, moreso, the first objects that are x higher then other numbers as a percentage or form of standard deviation.

So 50 is much higher then 10 and 5

10 is much higher then 3 or 2

However 9, 8 and 6 are much the same

Comment: your example looks like a list of dictionaries, not dictionary of dictionaries.. anyway, what was wrong about sorting?

Comment: Python dictionaries are unordered, so if you want to sort these entries by score you'll need to store them in something that is ordered like a list first. Afterwards you can just remove the lowest 25-40% which will be at the beginning of the list after a normal ascending sort.

Comment: Oh yes I meant to make it a list with dictionaries

Comment: In your edit the second example has scores of 4, 2 and 1 which, IMHO, fit the description of being "much the same" just as 9, 8 and 6 do. We need a more rigorous definition of when a score is "much higher" than the others? What was wrong with my arbitrary example of a score being too low if it was more than one standard deviation from the maximum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourdata = [{15: [32, 'massages']}, {45: [12, 'hair-salon']}, {23:[3, 'automotive service']}]

# transfer your data into a more usable format
data = [(score,cat,name) for dat in yourdata for cat,(score,name) in dat.iteritems()]

# sort on descending score
data.sort(reverse=True)

# throw away the low-scoring items
data = data[:int(len(data)*0.6 + 1)]
```

returns

```
[(32, 15, 'massages'), (12, 45, 'hair-salon')]
```

(the two highest-scoring items)

Comment: you could use heapq.nlargest() for readability instead of .sort()

Comment: The only thing is - if we make massages 15, hair salon 2, and automotive services 2, it still returns hair salon

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I would endorse the use of .nlargest over .sort for *efficiency* if we were getting only a small number of items from `data`; I am not sure the readability is significantly different.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution using [`heapq.nlargest()`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)

```
import heapq

data = [{15: [32, 'massages']}, {45: [12, 'hair-salon']}, {23:[3, 'automotive service']}]

N = int(len(data) * 0.6 + 1)
print heapq.nlargest(N, data, key = lambda x: next(x.itervalues())[0])
```

This prints:

```
[{15: [32, 'massages']}, {45: [12, 'hair-salon']}]
```

**Edit:** If you want to eliminate "*low scoring items*" then you need to define exactly what you mean by "*low scoring*".

Here's some code which takes an entirely arbitrary definition of "low scoring": a score is low if it is more than one standard deviation below the maximum:

```
import math

data = [{15: [32, 'massages']}, {45: [1, 'hair-salon']}, {23:[3, 'automotive service']}]

scores = [score for d in data for cat,(score,name) in d.iteritems()]
score_mean = sum(scores) / float(len(scores))
score_stdev = math.sqrt(sum(abs(s - score_mean)**2 for s in scores) / float(len(scores)))

print [d for d in data if next(d.itervalues())[0] > (max(scores) - score_stdev)]
```

This prints:

```
[{15: [32, 'massages']}]
```

Comment: Thanks, see edit - I gave some detail into what I mean by low scoring

Comment: formula for stdev is wrong. It should be [`sqrt(mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) (using numpy syntax)

Comment: Using `.itervalues` to only get the key is a little odd; why not just `next(d.iterkeys())`?

Comment: @lvc Actually I'm not getting the key, I'm getting the first element of the value. For example, given `{15: [32, 'massages']}` the key is 15, but the number I want is 32, which is the first element of the first value in the dictionary.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks. I fixed the stdev calculation. That'll teach me to do this in a rush.

Comment: @srgerg oh, right. Must be too early in the afternoon for me - I was getting confused between `itervalues` and `iteritems`.